# Find years where 22nd March will be a Tuesday

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to find out in which years between 2017 and 2100 (both inclusive) will the 22nd March be a Tuesday.

I tried using the `datetime` module but I couldn't figure out how...

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide your code so far

Comment: not that it's particular important (because 2100-3-22 isn't a Tuesday) but the range **including 2100** or **excluding 2100**? I find _in between_ a bit vague.

Comment: Sorry I had a for loop cricket_007 and inclusive MSeifert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **[calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)** module instead:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> [year for year in range(2017, 2101) if calendar.weekday(year, 3, 22) == calendar.TUESDAY]
[2022, 2033, 2039, 2044, 2050, 2061, 2067, 2072, 2078, 2089, 2095]
```

Comment: Wow this module is much better for this than datetime thanks!

Comment: Just a minor comment: If you want 2100 inclusive you need to use `range(2017, 2101)`. :)

Comment: `calendar.weekday` is just an alias for `datetime.date.weekday`. No need to load a separate module just for this purpose.

Comment: @zwer I presume OP was not using the `datetime` module anywhere else

Comment: @shash678 - I was commenting on the unnecessary use of the `calendar` module in the first place - the same can be achieved with `[year for year in range(2017, 2101) if datetime.date(year, 3, 22).weekday() == 1]` - because that's what essentially your code is doing, but at the cost of importing the whole `calendar` module and having an extra function call.

Comment: @zwer I think the readability of seeing TUESDAY in your code is worth it. Is this not one of the reasons the calendar module was made?

Comment: @shash678 - `calendar` provides nice facilities and convenience features for iterating over various calendar ranges, generating HTML calendars, dealing with different locales and calculating based on different week days... if you need to load all that just to get a `(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY) = range(7)` map, you're doing it wrong... But then we'd be arguing convenience vs effectiveness and that's rarely a fruitful discussion so I won't go there. I was merely suggesting a more effective approach that your answer translates to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) from the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

for year in range(2017, 2101):
    if datetime.date(year, 3, 22).isoweekday() == 2:  # 2 is Tuesday
        print(year)
```

or [`weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday):

```
import datetime

for year in range(2017, 2101):
    if datetime.date(year, 3, 22).weekday() == 1:  # now 1 is Tuesday
        print(year)
```

---

You can also use a comprehension to collect them in a list:

```
>>> [year for year in range(2017, 2101) if datetime.date(year, 3, 22).isoweekday() == 2]
[2022, 2033, 2039, 2044, 2050, 2061, 2067, 2072, 2078, 2089, 2095]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but how about using math instead of building hundreds of `datetime.datetime` objects just to throw them away?

```
# adjusted Zeller's formula, returns 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday ... 6 - Saturday
def get_weekday(y, m, d):  
    return (d+(13*((10+m)%12+1)-1)//5+y%100+y%100//4+(y//100)//4-2*(y//100))%7

start_year = 2017
end_year = 2100

target_date = 22
target_month = 2    # 0 - January, 1 - February ... 11 - December
target_weekday = 2  # 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday ... 6 - Saturday

years = [year for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1) if
         get_weekday(year, target_month, target_date) == target_weekday]
# gives: [2022, 2033, 2039, 2044, 2050, 2061, 2067, 2072, 2078, 2089, 2095]
```

Comment: A good alternative but in general I wouldn't recommend using self-implemented math if there's already a (built-in) library providing the math.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `datetime` module:

```
>>> tuesdays = [year for year in range(2017, 2101) if datetime.date(year, 3, 22).weekday() == 1]

>>> tuesdays
[2022, 2033, 2039, 2044, 2050, 2061, 2067, 2072, 2078, 2089, 2095]
```